# What are comma separated objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, console.log

Now I notice one thing, which is weird to me and I cannot find proper documentation. When I get the documents from collection with Mongoose.find() I log them to console. What's written is:

```
{ 
   name: 'first document'
},{
   name: 'second document'
}
```

(Of course they have _id's, but this is for the sake of simplicity.)

What is this in Javascript? I mean, I tried to do .forEach on it, but I get:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Array.forEach (native)
    ...
```

but, I can normally do something like:

```
User.find({}, function (err, users){
//        users.forEach(console.log('iterated')); -> returns error that I've described

    for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++){
        console.log('iterated');
    }
    console.log('users' + users);
});
```

**EDIT**

The type error is because of not passing function to `forEach` method, as mentioned in comments. But why is it not returning something like:

```
[{ 
   name: 'first document'
},{
   name: 'second document'
}}
```

Comment: You're not passing a function to `forEach()`. You're passing `undefined`, because that's what `console.log()` returns.

Comment: Do they have `_id`s inside or outside of the object? Is it a JSON string?

Comment: Don't confuse "what is logged to the console" is "JavaScript code"

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, you're right, I was stupid, forgot to make a function. Still, why is it returning comma separated objects? Why is it not like [{}, {}]?

Comment: @Tommz, because the string representation of arrays in Javascript is their elements, delimited by commas, without the surrounding square brackets. If you want to see those, you will have to add them by code.

Comment: Ok thanks. That was confusing me, because I know I sometimes saw [] when logging, but probably is left in the root object.

Comment: @Tommz: What you get back is probably not a plain Array, but an Array-like object, for example derived from an array but with added methods. When you log it, you will see the string representation of it rather than shown as an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a function to the `forEach` method:

```
users.forEach(function(v, i){
  console.log('User name = ' + v.name);
});
```

When you don't wrap `console.log('iterated')` in a function, it will first call the `log` method and use the return value to send to the `forEach` method.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> console.log('users' + users);
> ```

is casting your `users` to a string, [which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) will typically join them by commata. If you want to log them as usual, don't concat them with a string, but pass the `users` as a separate argument to `console.log`:

```
console.log('users', users);
```